# Anchored Links for SEO

Tags: seo

I have read a little about this but could not find a definitive answer anywhere. So, I thought of asking this question here.

I am building a Travel Guide which has lots of information divided into tabs. Each tab has its own content and keywords which I would like to rank for in SEO. Here's a screenshot of what my structure will be:

[image: The Tab Structure]

Each tab has unique content with its own keywords,images,videos,etc. So, for example, I would like to rank well when people search for 'Top things to do in Bali' and 'best time to visit bali' and show that particular tab by means of anchored links. So, it will be example.com/bali.html#top-things and example.com/bali.html#best-time respectively.

Do anchored links have any SEO value? Will they even show up on search v/s a normal link. So, if I am trying to rank for the keyword Top things in Bali, which URL is better? example.com/bali.html#top-things or example.com/bali/top-things

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about what markup search engines like are not suited for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Quentin - Sorry didn't know this wasn't suitable for SO. Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Delete your question and ask on [webmasters.se].  Make sure to read the [tag:seo] tag to see why.

Answer (score 1):

For a search engine, the anchors don't matter : Wikipedia uses them intensively, but I still haven't seen any link pointing to a specific anchored content from any SERP.

In a way, that's easy to understand : an anchor can be something like this :

```html
<a name="my_anchor">My Anchor</a>
```

Or something like this, which is far more semantically right :

```html
<anyHTMLTag id="anchor_name">my content here</anyHTMLTag>
```

Because an anchor can link to any `id` on the page.

Regarding your example, Google and other search engines will consider all of your content to be different paragraphs of the same page. If your purpose is to draw attention to a very specific zone of your page from the SERPs, that won't work.

Some years ago, when Google did not https encode their results page, a hook could have been used (Detecting the search query), but that's not the case anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Interlinking is important part of SEO. Keep in mind while you creating Anchored make it in Heading tag that will be more effective. anchored text is use full to target Keywords that also important and It is easy to share your pages links.

Answer (score -1):

The anchor link syntax for you website content will be equal to

```
<a href="" text="" target="_blank" > Your target keyword </a>
```

Select the target text from your content that you want to include anchor link.